# close dialog without showing user “exe has stopped working” message

Tags: c++, qt

MainWindow.cpp

```
Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog->show();
```

Dialog.cpp

```
Dialog::Dialog(String filename, vector<double> x, int y)
{
   filename_ = filename; 
   x_ = x;
   opena();
}
void Dialog::opena()
{
  try
  {
    A = new A(filename_);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    close();
  }
}
```

A.cpp

```
A::A(String filename)
{
  ifstream file(filename);
  if (!file)
  {
    throw runtime_error(“nono”);
  }
}
```

When I got runtime error from A.cpp in dialog.cpp, I just want to close dialog and I dont want my program to be crashed.
Now, the code above shows “exe has stopped working” message.
How can I just close the dialog without showing users “exe has stopped working” message?

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but try using the `deleteLater()` slot.

Comment: Do file operations out of the A:: ctor, better by something like `bool A::openAndRead()`. Handle the true/false return at `Dialog::opena()`. Also move ctors out of `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].  Also, please [indent your code](http://format.krzaq.cc/)

Comment: I think it is a minimal reproducible example. I just indented my code.

Comment: I think it's too minimal. However I believe @JimmyG  has the solution that should work.

Comment: The code you posted works quite fine, the problem must be elsewhere (i.e. somewhere in the code you did *not* post). @JimmyG closing a `QDialog` means hiding it, deletion doesn't automatically occur.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I understand deletion and hiding, but considering the ultra-minimalistic code, all I have to go on is that the program just pops up a dialog and exits.

Comment: @JimmyG I agree one can only guess, here ...

Comment: thanks. How can I delete the Qdialog instead of closing/hiding it?